# Magento 2: How to load all product images from external url in front end and backend?

Tags: magento2, frontend, product-images, backend

Magento 2, How to load all product images from external url in front end and backend

Comment: do you mean to change the base URL of images?

Comment: Yes need to change base , small and thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

We can change the media base URL from the below configuration.

> Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web > Base URLs > Base URL for User Media Files

> Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web > Base URLs (Secure) > Base URL for User Media Files

e.g)

If we set **Base URL for User Media Files** is `https://www.example.com/` all the media images will be using the `https://www.example.com/` as the base URL.

We mainly used the above configuration to use CDN for media.

Comment: No i need the external url for product images intead of images and videos attribute it will show another server